# nan when executing printf

Tags: c, math.h

When I execute program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

double exponential(double u);

double exponential(double u)
{
    double a = (double)rand();
    return (-u * log(1.0 - a));
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%e\n",exponential(2.3));
    return 0;
}
```

I obtain:

```
nan
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried to print the value of `a` in your `exponential()`?

Comment: just a comment -- this kind of forward declaration is absolutely not necessary. If you really want to do this in one file, leave the func declaration on top, and put the definition to the bottom of your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `rand()` returns an integer (between 0 and `RAND_MAX`), most often this integer is larger than 1 and your `log` expression will be negative. `log` returns `NaN` (not a number) for negative inputs.